# c# sql update database set datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, database, wpf, datagrid

I am working with an application in c# where i get data from database. The application have some fields like: barcode, product, qty, price,  total

I use this code to get data from database:

```
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = Bilanc; Integrated Security = true");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Product", con); // Using a Store Procedure.
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Barcode", txtcode.Text);




            dtg.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;//Set the DataGrid ItemSource to this new generated DataTable

            con.Open();//Open the SQL connection

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();//Create a SqlDataReader

            while (reader.Read())//For each row that the SQL query returns do
            {
                DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();//Create new DataRow to populate the DataTable (which is currently binded to the DataGrid)
                dr[0] = reader[0];//Fill DataTable column 0 current row (Product) with reader[0] (Product from sql)
                dr[1] = reader[1];
                dr[2] = reader[2];
                dr[3] = reader[3];
                dr[4] = reader[4];


                dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);//Add the new created DataRow to the DataTable
                txtcode.Text = "";

                object sumObject;
                sumObject = dataTable.Compute("Sum(Total)", "");
                txttot.Text = sumObject.ToString();

            }





        }

    }
```

the xaml code

```
           <Grid>

       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="700"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
    <TextBox Name="txtb"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Label Name="lblkodi" Content="Kodi"/>
        <Label Name="lblpershkrimi" Margin="900,0,0,0" Content="Pershkrimi" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox  Name="txtkodi" Width="400" Height="30" KeyDown="kerko" />
        <TextBox Name="txtpershkrimi"  Margin="480,0,0,0" Width="400" Height="30" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBox Name="txttot" Width="350"  Height="80" BorderBrush="Black" Text="0" FontSize="50" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="DarkBlue"/>

    </StackPanel>




            <StackPanel Grid.Row="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
              <DataGrid Name="dtg" CurrentCellChanged="data" Height="650"  
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,21,0,0"   
                VerticalAlignment="Top" RowHeight="30" ColumnWidth="150" 
               RowBackground="LightYellow" 
            AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" 
           AutoGenerateColumns="True" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4" 
      CanUserResizeColumns="True" Foreground="Black" Width="1250"  />
    </StackPanel>










    <StackPanel Grid.Row="6" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="btnfaturo" Width="170" Content="Faturo" Height="60" 
          Click="btnfaturo_Click" Margin="40,0,0,0" />
        <Button Name="btnfatura" Width="170" Content="Fatura e rregullt" 
      Height="60" Click="btnfatura_Click" />
        <Button Name="btnanulo" Width="170" Content="Hiq Artikuj(F7)" 
        Height="60" Click="btnanulo_Click" />
        <Button Name="btnzbritje" Width="170" Content="Zbritje ne total" Height="60" Click="btnzbritje_Click" />
        <Button Name="btncmimi" Width="170" Content="Ndrysho Cmimin" Height="60" Click="btncmimi_Click" />
        <Button Name="btnpershkrim" Width="170" Content="Sipas pershkrimit" Height="60" Click="btnpershkrim_Click" KeyDown="F1" />
        <Button Name="btnlc" Width="170" Content="LC" Height="60"  />
    </StackPanel>
```

Stored Procedure

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[product]
      @Barcode varchar (50) = null,
      @Product varchar (50) = null,
       @price int = null,
      @qty int = null,
       @tax varchar (50) = null

       AS

      SELECT[Barcode]
   ,[Product]
  ,[Price]
  ,[qty]
  ,[tax]

   FROM [Bilanc].[dbo].[artiku]
  Where Barcode LIKE @Barcode
```

The code works fine, but i am stucked to another problem. For example the user changes the qty in Data Grid from 1 to 3 i want that also the qty in database to be deducted for 3 items(to be updated) after the user hit the button
If anyone could help me cause i am new to programming and this is a homework that i must finish
Thanks to anyone.

Comment: I think we need to know more information about the database and maybe see the xaml.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: This still doesnt tell us anything about the database. When I say That I woudl like to know maybe what your StoredProcedure looks like. that will tell us table names.

Comment: As its homework - what has your instructor covered about updating databases?

Comment: I have a homework to retrieve data from sql into datagrid, and after editing update the database. Also i have another task that  the edited data to be saved to another table

Comment: Okay, I'm going to create a sample here. Then I will message you and try to send for you to review.

Comment: @lex, I have created something similar to what you're describing here. if you message me an email address I will mail it to you. Please note, I didn't do exactly what your are asking here, because it is important for you to figure some out but you can look at what I've done and implement something similar.

Comment: leximber@gmail.com.          thank you very much